# Consulta linq complexa ao passar parâmetros

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, expressões-lambda

Preciso fazer uma consulta linq, mas estou tendo uma dificuldade para fazer. Eu possuo 5 filtros na página. Sendo que três deles vêm de três dropdown(select). Eu só poderei considerar os select, caso o texto neles sejam diferentes de "SEM FILTRO", primeiro passo. O último select, tem apenas duas linhas, sendo a primeira GERAL e a segunda SOUZA CRUZ. Se for geral, deverá trazer tudo que está no campo visao, senão somente aquilo que é souza cruz. Como eu não consigo dar um if dentro de uma linq, fico com essa dificuldade. Tenho essa consulta, que um colega me passou aqui nesse forum, dessa forma, mas encontro dificuldade para colocar mais filtros nesse meu novo contexto. A consulta que o Morrison me passou foi essa e atendeu para o que eu solicitei.

```
.Where(cn => (cn.x1.a1.o2.NumOs == Convert.ToInt32(_osparceiro)) && (_cnpj == "" || cn.cnpj == _cnpj))
```

Agora estou com dificuldade para fazer a minha. Veja o meu método:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult MontaResultadoPdv(string _cnpj, string _contato, string _filtrarrede, string _filtarstatus, string _visao)
        {
            V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();

            var resultadopdv = (from pdv in db.T_PDV
                                    .Where(res => (res.CNPJ == "" || res.CNPJ == _cnpj))
                                select new { 
                                            pdv.RazaoSocial,
                                            pdv.}).ToList(); 

            return Json(new {  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Esses são os parâmetros que vêm dos selects:

```
string _filtrarrede, string _filtarstatus, string _visao
```

Se vir null ou vazio, por exemplo, a consulta me dará um resultado não esperado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, talvez isso ajude você:

```
var resultadopdv = (from pdv in db.T_PDV
            .Where(res => (res.CNPJ == "" || res.CNPJ == _cnpj))
        select new { 
                    pdv.RazaoSocial,
                    pdv.});

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filtrarrede))
    resultadopdv = resultadopdv.Where(e => e.rede == _filtrarrede);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_filtarstatus))
    resultadopdv = resultadopdv.Where(e => e.status == _filtarstatus);
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_visao))
    resultadopdv = resultadopdv.Where(e => e.visao == _visao);

return Json(resultadopdv.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Deixame entender. Eu posso fazer as condições(Where) fora da expressão, ou seja, como se fosse uma outra expressão. legal isso, vou testar e já fecho o post, caso dê tudo certo.

Comment: Lembrando uma coisa importante. A consulta não é executada antes de chamar o método `ToList()`. Logo você pode preparar toda a consulta com base nos parâmetros que você recebeu sem prejudicar a performance.

Comment: @pnet, esqueci de atribuir o resultado do `Where` para a variável. Dá uma olhada na edição.

Comment: Perfeito ... juntando a resposta e a explicação @Reiksiel daria a resposta final!